# Assemble Web page from HTML template, CSS template and HTML content pages

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a site where most pages have the same layout, only content and possibly the background image is different. Same HTML and CSS, with only difference in section and background-image. This is what I have been doing when I create a new page:

- Create a clean HTML file with the content I want to add - new_content.html, and a background image new_content.jpg to go with it
- Make a copy of HTML template page and name it new_page.html
- Copy the contents of new_content.html to  in new_page.html.
- Modify the CSS to set the background.
- On index.html, create a link to the new page.

There is a lot of repetition, and identical pages with only one div difference. I would also like to separate the content from page design, so that I could simply add a link on index.html that would do something like [mix of HTML and pseudocode only to illustrate what I want to do]:

```
<a href="page_template.html(new_content.html, new_content.jpg)>
```

I am new to this all, just trying to streamline how to make my own page work.  Javascript I can cut and paste, and usually figure out how it works.

Comment: There are many templating systems and approaches - but investigate the <template></template> html5 tag. Its great, but IE doesn't support it as well as other browsers.

Comment: php templates might be the go https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+template+for+web+pages&t=lm&ia=web

Comment: Thank you.  When I am ready to jump into PHP, I will know where to look.  The problem really was that I did not know how to formulate my duckduckgo, so I wouldn't just be offered 'ready-made web site templates.'

Comment: Being new to Stackoverflow - One more question.  Now that I have my answer, do you think I should
a) keep this question online, because someone else might benefit of it.
b) delete it because it has already been explained elsewhere, and only adds clutter to the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. HTML is static. To create dynamic content you need something like PHP, XML/XSL or a CMS (Content Management System).